# php script File not uploading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on zend framework and when ever i try to upload a file it gives me following error.
Kindly let me know how can i give the permission to upload the file and it foesn't result to failing in upload stream

Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webmin\application\uploads\1335352110_123.avi) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webmin\application\controllers\StimulusController.php on line 266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing access rights on the directory *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webmin\application\uploads*

Comment: Here is how to do it: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/ Give full access or write access to IIS.

Comment: i didn't change anything in the code just set permissions of folder and it worked...